# What are the rules for forced movement into and out of water and flying?

Tags: dnd-4e, forced-movement, flight

The rules say that pulling, pushing and sliding is normally horizontal movement.  However that changes in water or for flying creatures, where the forced movement can be in any direction.

What about the transitions?

**1.** Can I pull, push or slide a target off of dry land into a body of water? Is there a difference between a dock (straight drop) and a beach (gradual slope)?

**1a.** If the creature is able to fly, but is not currently flying, does he hover over the water or fall in?

**2.** Can I pull, push or slide a target out of water onto dry land? Is there a difference between a dock (straight drop) and a beach (gradual slope)?

**3.** Can I pull, push or slide a target that is able to fly, but is not currently flying, into the air to a hovering position?

**4.** Can I pull, push or slide a target that is flying over water into the water?

Comment: Although they are related, there's a *lot* of separate questions in here.  Any chance you could break this up?

Comment: Perhaps the question could be more succinctly stated as "can movement mode of the target of forced movement be changed?" @iszi, @dpatch

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**1.** Yes,  Just like push/pull/slide someone over a cliff, the same applies here.  If it is a beach or river bank then they get wet.  If it is a dock or cliff then they fall (save if applicable), then get wet.  See below.

**1a.** That would be up to the creature and any other affects on the creature, but I would say they fly.  See below.

**2.** No, and Yes See below.
**3.** No, see below.
**4.** Yes (sort of), see below.

Rules from DDI

Slide: PHB1 pg285; MM1 pg283 - When you slide a creature, there’s no restriction on the direction you can move it.

Pull: PHB1 pg285; MM1 pg282 - When you pull a creature, each square you move it must bring it nearer to you.

Push: PHB1 pg285; MM1 pg282 - When you push a creature, each square you move it must place it farther away from you.

Forced Movement: PHB1 pg285; MM1 pg311
Movement that a creature is compelled to do, specifically a pull, a push, or a slide. A creature can be moved in other ways, such as through teleportation, but only pulls, pushes, and slides are technically forced movement.

Two-Dimensional: Forced movement is normally two-dimensional; all the squares of the movement must be on the same horizontal plane. Forced movement can become three-dimensional when the target is flying, is moved through a substance such as water, or is on a non-horizontal surface, such as an incline, that supports it. This means an earthbound target cannot normally be pushed to a square in the air, but a hovering target can be. Similarly, a target can be pulled down a flight of stairs, and it can be slid in any direction underwater.

Comment: If you push/pull/slide a target off a dock, they should get a save vs. falling as normal.

Comment: Your answer to #1 makes sense, but I don't think any of the others are supported by the rules you quoted. Maybe I'm missing something? I'm also unclear on the definition of "earthbound" -- Unable to fly or not currently flying?

Comment: You are correct, I updated.  Number 2 is sort of a mixed question and confused me.